# Keen.io not adjusting for daylight savings time on yearly interval?

Tags: keen-io

We are making a query against Keen (via Python) at several different intervals.

For each, we are passing the optional parameter `timezone` as a **[named timezone](https://keen.io/docs/api/#named-timezones)** rather than absolute offset, so that it will account for Daylight Savings Time, eg: `"America/New_York"`

This is working for 3 of the intervals.

**Daily** appropriately accounts for DST...

```
{
  timeframe: {
    start: "2016-11-05T04:00:00.000Z",
    end:   "2016-11-06T04:00:00.000Z"
  },
  value: [ ... ],
},
{
  timeframe: {
    start: "2016-11-06T04:00:00.000Z",
    end:   "2016-11-07T05:00:00.000Z"
  },
  value: [ ... ],
},
{
  timeframe: {
    start: "2016-11-07T05:00:00.000Z",
    end:   "2016-11-08T05:00:00.000Z"
  },
  value: [ ... ],
}
```

... as does **weekly**...

```
{
  timeframe: {
    start: "2016-11-06T04:00:00.000Z",
    end:   "2016-11-13T05:00:00.000Z"
  },
  value: [ ... ],
},
...
{
  timeframe: {
    start: "2017-03-12T05:00:00.000Z",
    end:   "2017-03-19T04:00:00.000Z"
  },
  value: [ ... ],
}
```

... and even **monthly**.

```
{
  timeframe: {
    start: "2016-11-01T04:00:00.000Z",
    end:   "2016-12-01T05:00:00.000Z"
  },
  value: [ ... ],
},
...
{
  timeframe: {
    start: "2017-03-01T05:00:00.000Z",
    end:   "2017-04-01T04:00:00.000Z"
  },
  value: [ ... ],
}
```

**Yearly**, however, does **not** adjust for DST...

```
{
  timeframe: {
    start: "2016-11-01T04:00:00.000Z",
    end:   "2017-01-01T04:00:00.000Z"
  },
  value: [ ... ],
},
...
{
  timeframe: {
    start: "2017-01-01T04:00:00.000Z",
    end:   "2017-11-01T04:00:00.000Z"
  },
  value: [ ... ],
}
```

... as the start of the second timeframe (Jan 01) should be `T05:...` offset instead of `T04:...`, much like the previous intervals. Additionally, because the end of the first timeframe is not DST-adjusted, it shows as `2017-01-01T04:...` instead of `2016-12-31T05:...`.

Literally nothing is changing between these queries, other than the `interval` param.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't all of November 1st 2016, January 1st 2017, and November 1st 2017 within DST for New York? This looks like it is doing exactly what it should.

Comment: November 1 is within DST for 2016/2017 (since DST ends the first weekend of November) so the `04:00:00Z` makes sense... December & January, however, are outside of DST so they should be -5 hours from UTC, not -4.. The first yearly timeframe ends `2017-01-01T04...Z`, which outside of DST is 5 hours difference from EST, so it's ending 2016 on December 31, 11:00pm instead of midnight.. As well, it's starting 2017 at the same time

Comment: Have you tried this via curl to verify it isn't an SDK bug? Also, sorry about the confusion earlier. DST confuses the heck out of me.

Comment: Haha same, hopefully by the time I retire I'll understand DST... As for curl, I need to try that actually - we aren't using the actual Keen Python client to make the call, we're just manually hitting the URL and parsing the results - but perhaps we aren't generating headers properly.